# BATCH File: For /F Loop with Dsget only returns the second line and not the first line

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, variables, token, echo

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

For /F "tokens=1" %%g in ('cmd /c whoami') do (set loggedinusername=%%g)
set loggedinusername=%loggedinusername:~6%
echo %loggedinusername%


For /F "Tokens=1 eol==" %%a in ('dsquery user -samid %loggedinusername% ^|dsget user -dept ^|find /V "dept"') do (set deptname=%%a)

echo deptname equals %deptname%
```

I was hoping if someone could have a look at this little bit of batch code and tell me were I am going wrong. The first part grabbing the username works fine, and it uses the variable successfully in the second FOR /F.

However, as you can see in the output below, it does successfully find the department name, but when I output the variable it only returns the dsget succeeded message and not the line above.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated, Cheers

```
C:\Users\*****\Desktop>for /F "Tokens=1 eol==" %a in ('dsquery user -samid USERNAME |dsget user -dept |find /V "dept"') do (set deptname=%a )

C:\Users\*****\Desktop>(set deptname=IT )

C:\Users\*****\Desktop>(set deptname=dsget )

C:\Users\*****\Desktop>echo deptname equals dsget
deptname equals dsget`
```

Comment: I would need to see the real world output of each of those command runs individually from the command line to determine why the `FOR` command isn't giving you the result you want.

Comment: I will suggest that you may wish to look at the Command Prompt output from entering `for /?`, because it's not clear from your code whether you understand how to use `eol`. Your current code appears to be ignoring any lines which contain the case insensitive string dept, and do not begin with the character `=`. Is that what you intended it to do? Also what happens is that you set a variable named `deptname` to the value `IT`, then you overwrite that same variable name with the next line `dsget`. The simplest way to prevent the overwrite, is to use `If Not Defined deptname Set "deptname=%a"`.

Comment: @Compo - Thank you some much for your help and explaining where I was going wrong. You're absolutely right I don't understand the correct usage of eol ( I was grasping at straws trying to figure out where I was going wrong :-) ) Definitly a bit more study needed of these commands. (updated working code added to original post)

Comment: @wideopen, please give one, more, or all of the examples in my answer a try. _Also please do not add answers to your question, the answer area is where those belong._

Comment: @Compo - sorry about that I had added the update to the question before I saw your comment. I'll definitely give your examples a try, thanks again for your help, cheers

Comment: @wideopen, no problem I've rolled it back to how it was, before your last edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options availaably to you, however as I cannot use those commands, or see the actual output you're receiving, you'll have to use, or adapt, one of the following examples.

If you knew that the department name would never begin with the character `d`, you could just use:

```batch-file
For /F "EOL=d Delims=" %%G In ('dsquery user -samid USERNAME ^| dsget user -dept') Do Set "deptname=%%G"
```

However, if it is possible for the department name to begin with `d`, you could use an additional `find` command:

```batch-file
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('dsquery user -samid USERNAME ^| dsget user -dept ^| find /v "dept" ^| find /v "dsget"') Do Set "deptname=%%G"
```

Or use the`findstr` command instead:

```batch-file
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('dsquery user -samid USERNAME ^| dsget user -dept ^| findstr /v "dept dsget"') Do Set "deptname=%%G"
```

Alternatively you could use the idea I provided in the comment section:

```batch-file
Set "deptname="
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('dsquery user -samid USERNAME ^| dsget user -dept ^| find /v "dept"') Do If Not Defined deptname Set "deptname=%%G"
```

Other possible alternatives may include:

If the first line is always dept:

```batch-file
For /F Skip^=1^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('dsquery user -samid USERNAME ^| dsget user -dept') Do Set "deptname=%%G" & GoTo Next
:Next
```

*If there's a blank first line and the second line is `dept`, then change `Skip^=1^` to `Skip^=2^`*

If you knew all of the department names, then you could possibly put those in a `findstr` match too:

```batch-file
Set "depts=Design Finance IT Workshop"
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('dsquery user -samid USERNAME ^| dsget user -dept ^| findstr /i "%depts%"') Do Set "deptname=%%G"
```